# HTML Email Outlook Issue

Tags: html, email

Im having a problem with Hotmail's email rendering. And im looking for an answer to this problem if anyone has overcome it.

Please find my code below.

```
 <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:center;">
     <ul style="margin:0; padding:0;">
         <li style="display:inline; color:#fcb01a; margin:0;">&bull; <span style="color:#000000;">Item 1</span></li>
         <li style="display:inline; color:#fcb01a; margin:0;">&bull; <span style="color:#000000;">Item 2</span></li>
         <li style="display:inline; color:#fcb01a; margin:0;">&bull; <span style="color:#000000;">Item 3</span></li>
         <li style="display:inline; color:#fcb01a; margin:0;">&bull; <span style="color:#000000;">BMW</span></li>
         <li style="display:inline; color:#fcb01a; margin:0;">&bull; <span style="color:#000000;">Item 4</span></li>
     </ul>    
 </td>
```

The issue is this:
On hotmail a margin is added below the  and unfortunately margin:0 is not supported. any ideas on how to remove the margin from this?

Notes:
This is for an email so any answer must be inline CSS or HTML.
The issue is definitely the ul element (using firebug in emailonacid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try setting margin-top:0, margin-bottom:0 etc ... The css shortcuts are not well supported.

Answer (score 0):

Campaign monitor's guide http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css say margin is working fine on Outlook... But display isn't supported... May be a clue?